# Statistical test for boolean value groups

Tags: statistics, boolean-algebra, binomial-distribution, hypothesis-testing

## Intro

This question is somewhat of a *prequel* to this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference) - but can be seen also as a standalone!

I have two distinct populations/measurements of boolean values: $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^{m_1},x_i \in \{0,1\},|x|=m_1$ and $\{y_i\}_{i=1}^{m_2},y_i\in\{0,1\},|y|=m_2$. Each $x_i$ (and $y_i$) is independent of the other boolean values.

These numbers represent *activity* values ($1$ = *active*, $0$ = *inactive*) of two different group of models, namely the *good* ones ($x$'s) and the *bad* ones ($y$'s). **I wanted to find a measurement of how much the (mean) activity of the good models is different than the bad models' activity**. So, I started with the average values $a_1=mean(x)$ and $a_2=mean(y)$ and took the difference: $d=a_1-a_2$. Then I wanted to include a *penalty* related to the amount of models $m_1,m_2$ and this was solved in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference) by introducing a proper scaling function for the difference $d$.

## The problem

I was considering that if I had two populations of continuous measurements, then I would probably do a *Wilcoxon Rank Sum* test (use `wilcox.test` in `R` for example) and get also a *p-value* + *location parameter shift* estimation (a kind of $d$ as is in the respective implementation) for this (for the boolean case, ranking methods are useless right?). So, the *p-value* would tell how sure I am about this difference - which is kind of what I wanted to solve *numerically* (by let's say inserting the uncertainty in the final formula) in this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547139/formula-for-weighted-average-difference).

All in all, I need a **statistical test** that would compare boolean values and get me as a result a *p-value* and the *d* difference (or similar) so to speak.

## What I tried

So, since I work with two different and independent set of boolean values $\{x_i\}$ and $\{y_i\}$ the words **binomial distribution** and **bionomial test** came into my mind (from loooong ago :) But after reading about them for a while and playing with the respective `R` functions, it turned out not I wanted this to be.

The most significant problem for me was that I do not know the *probability of success*, i.e. $p=P(x_i=1)$ (or $y_i$ for that matter) - actually that's what I want to know for each model category! I tried to use the average $a_1=mean(x)=p$ and then to take a value of the cumulative distribution but it does not give results *representative* to what I want (the average activity). And the binomial test does not come close to what I want either.

For example: $x=\{0,0,0,0,1,0\}, m_1=n=6,p=1/6=0.1667$ and then I would calculate the $P(X\geq 1)=0.665$, which is way higher than expected.

---

Maybe I am overthinking it, but I believe there should be something close to what I want to do with this boolean dataset that I have. Any directions for distribution(s) or statistical tests that can accommodate my case are welcome!

---

Also posted on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/451331/statistical-test-for-boolean-value-groups).

Comment: the Cross Validated group might attract more attention on this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I have posted it also there. If it get any activity/answers, I will delete this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For continuous measurements of two random boolean variables, in a setting in which you'd like to combine the distributions and consider them as one, I'd recommend a [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

It's a close approximation to a binomial and the concept of the "average frequency of event $A$" and the "average frequency of event $B$" are clearly additive since the average frequency (per unit time) of events $A$ and $B$ is the sum of the two means.

Comment: Interesting! I believe this question is relavant then: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9561/checking-if-two-poisson-samples-have-the-same-mean. The paper the answer cites does exactly that: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0378375802004081